# Debian keeps hanging, may be graphics driver issue

Tags: debian, xorg, crash, i915

For the past few days, my Debian install keeps randomly hanging every 5-30 minutes. The screen freezes. Sometimes GDM kicks me back to the login screen after a little while. Other times it just completely freezes. It started after I did a dist-upgrade for the first time in a few weeks, inc upgrading to Gnome 3.20.

Here's what I found in the syslog, a similar set of messages appear each time:

```
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) [mi] EQ overflowing.  Additional events will be discarded until existing events are processed.
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE)
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) Backtrace:
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x55fd88968f6e]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (mieqEnqueue+0x253) [0x55fd8894aa33]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55fd88823632]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xf86PostMotionEvent+0xd6) [0x55fd8885a956]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so (0x7f0fbb634000+0x5f89) [0x7f0fbb639f$
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so (0x7f0fbb634000+0x7532) [0x7f0fbb63b5$
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x55fd887b7000+0x940f8) [0x55fd8884b0f8]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x55fd887b7000+0xb9392) [0x55fd88870392]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f0fc3a6d000+0x334e0) [0x7f0fc3aa04e0]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (ioctl+0x5) [0x7f0fc3b4e4f5]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f0fbf3ef000+0x24f5d) [0x7f0fbf413f$
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f0fbf3ef000+0x28904) [0x7f0fbf4179$
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7f0fbf3ef000+0x5c3ee) [0x7f0fbf44b3$
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (BlockHandler+0x4a) [0x55fd8880f5ba]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 14: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (WaitForSomething+0x163) [0x55fd88965c33]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 15: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x55fd887b7000+0x53a1e) [0x55fd8880aa1e]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 16: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x55fd887b7000+0x57c03) [0x55fd8880ec03]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f0fc3a8d5f0]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) 18: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x29) [0x55fd887f8f99]
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE)
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) [mi] These backtraces from mieqEnqueue may point to a culprit higher up the stack.
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) [mi] mieq is *NOT* the cause.  It is a victim.
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet kernel: [ 1087.627729] [drm] stuck on render ring
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet kernel: [ 1087.634979] [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 8:0:0xfffffffe, in Xorg [1162], reason: Ring hung, action: reset
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet kernel: [ 1087.634995] [drm] GPU hangs can indicate a bug anywhere in the entire gfx stack, including userspace.
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet kernel: [ 1087.635004] [drm] Please file a _new_ bug report on bugs.freedesktop.org against DRI -> DRM/Intel
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet kernel: [ 1087.635012] [drm] drm/i915 developers can then reassign to the right component if it's not a kernel issue.
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet kernel: [ 1087.635019] [drm] The gpu crash dump is required to analyze gpu hangs, so please always attach it.
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet kernel: [ 1087.635029] [drm] GPU crash dump saved to /sys/class/drm/card0/error
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet kernel: [ 1087.641887] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: [mi] Increasing EQ size to 1024 to prevent dropped events.
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: [mi] EQ processing has resumed after 37 dropped events.
Jun 17 11:18:10 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: [mi] This may be caused by a misbehaving driver monopolizing the server's resources.
Jun 17 11:18:13 piglet pulseaudio[916]: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
Jun 17 11:18:18 piglet kernel: [ 1095.635999] [drm] stuck on render ring
Jun 17 11:18:18 piglet kernel: [ 1095.642984] [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 8:0:0xfffffffe, in Xorg [1162], reason: Ring hung, action: reset
Jun 17 11:18:18 piglet kernel: [ 1095.643414] [drm:i915_set_reset_status [i915]] *ERROR* gpu hanging too fast, banning!
Jun 17 11:18:18 piglet kernel: [ 1095.646268] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
Jun 17 11:18:18 piglet /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1160]: (EE) intel(0): Failed to submit rendering commands (Input/output error), disabling acceleration.
```

My system is completely up to date, on Debian stretch.

How can I try to stop this? Could I switch drivers from the Intel i915 driver? Or disable the DRM or some other element in the grub config?

Answer (score 1):

The log tells you what you should do about it:

> GPU hangs can indicate a bug anywhere in the entire gfx stack, including userspace.
>
> Please file a *new* bug report on bugs.freedesktop.org against DRI -> DRM/Intel
> drm/i915 developers can then reassign to the right component if it's not a kernel issue.
>
> The gpu crash dump is required to analyze gpu hangs, so please always attach it.
> GPU crash dump saved to `/sys/class/drm/card0/error`

This won't fix your issue immediately (unless it's a known bug with a fix somewhere already), but it will help it get fixed; the `i915` developers are quite reactive.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've found a similar bug report so have added a comment. I've noticed I don't get the problem with an older kernel so I'll revert to that for now.